# Set "Arial" as the default font in the text editor in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

What is the best way to set `Arial` font as the default font in the text editor in Sitecore 8? I have looked around and seen instructions on changing the `toolsfile.xml`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know default setting for RTE (at least for the one in Content Editor) is `font-family: Arial, sans-serif;` (set in `/default.css` file).

You can override it e.g. by changing the content of `sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Editor.css` and adding `body { font-family: another-font }`.

You may need to clear your browser cache before you can see the change in RTE.